# Vue image delays render process

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have the following problem: I'm loading an image with dynamic src like this

```
:style="{ background: `url(${imageSrc}) center` }"
```

where imageSrc is

```
require(`@/assets/img/${this.image}`)
```

Everything is working fine but I tried to abstract my components and encountered some strange behaviour. This code was located in Podcast.vue -> worked just perfect as expected. I created a new file called PostList.vue and I'm passing the src as a prop. If I then use the PostList component in Podcast, the Podcast page doesn't open directly on click as expected - instead it waits until the image is fully loaded and opens the page afterwards. This creates a delay of 3-5s, which is not an option. It hasn't something to do with the image passed as prop, it's exactly the same when I hardcode the path. If I just take my code from PostList again and use it directly in Podcast.vue - I'm getting the old behaviour back. It is definetly because of the image, if I comment out the require line - no delay. This only happens if it's the first time after pageload, afterwards it's cached.

Here is my complete code:

PostList.vue

```
<template>
  <div>

    <Breadcrumbs />

    <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
      <v-card class="custom-card-height">
        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex hidden-sm-and-down md6 pa-0 class="pic-cell" v-if="imageSrc">
            <img :src="imageSrc" :alt="postType">
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex md6 pa-0 class="meditation-content">
            <v-layout row wrap v-if="!loading">
              <v-flex xs6 sm3 class="entry" text-xs-center
                v-for="item of entries"
                :key="item.slug"
                @click="loadItem(item)"
              >
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                  <div slot="activator">
                    <div class="svg-inline" v-html="icon"></div>
                    <h4># {{ item.number }}</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tooltip-content">
                    <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
                    <div v-html="item.content"></div>
                  </div>
                </v-tooltip>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <LoadingSpinner v-else />
            <Pagination 
              v-if="pageCount"
              :page="page" 
              :pageCount="pageCount"
              @onPaginationInput="paginationHandler"
            />
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>

      <BackButton :backString="backString" :link="backLink" />

    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PostMixin from '@/shared/mixins/post.mixin'
import EventBus from '@/shared/eventBus.js'
export default {
  name: 'post-list',
  mixins: [PostMixin],
  props: {
    postIcon: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    postType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      icon: null,
      imageSrc: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.icon = require(`@/assets/icons/${this.postIcon}`)
    this.imageSrc = require(`@/assets/img/${this.image}`)
  },
  methods: {
    loadItem (item) {
      let eventString = ''
      switch (this.postType) {
        case 'meditation': eventString = 'playMeditation'; break
        case 'podcast': eventString = 'playPodcast'; break
        default: console.log('kein Posttype in PostIconList.vue')
      }
      EventBus.$emit(eventString, item)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Podcast.vue

```
<template>
  <PostList
    postType="podcast"
    postIcon="Icon_Pod_grau.svg"
    image="headphone-1868612_1920.jpg"
    backString="Zurück auf's Sofa"
    backLink="/sofa"
  />
</template>

<script>
import PostList from '@/components/PostList'
export default {
  name: 'kopfhoerer',
  components: {
    PostList
  }
}
</script>
```

post.mixin.js

```
import Service from '@/shared/services/post.service'
import BackButton from '@/components/BackButton'
import LoadingSpinner from '@/components/LoadingSpinner'
import Breadcrumbs from '@/components/Breadcrumbs'
import Pagination from '@/components/Pagination'

export default {
  components: {
    BackButton,
    LoadingSpinner,
    Breadcrumbs,
    Pagination
  },
  props: {
    postType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    baseType: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
    detailLinkBase: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    backLink: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    backString: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      service: {},
      entries: {},
      loading: true,
      page: 1,
      pageCount: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.service = new Service(this.postType, this.baseType)
    this.getPostList()
    this.getMetaData()
  },
  methods: {
    getPostList () {
      this.loading = true
      this.service.getPostList(this.page, this.activeCategory, this.activeAuthor).then(data => {
        this.entries = data
        this.loading = false
        this.pageCount = this.service.pages
      })
    },
    getMetaData () {
      this.service.getMetaData().then(data => {
        if (data.categories) this.categories = data.categories
        if (data.authors) this.authors = data.authors
      })
    },
    paginationHandler (page) {
      this.page = page
      this.getPostList()
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are setting the `imageSrc` property on `created()` method, this means that the code inside `created()` is gonna be executed before the component mounts, that's why you are getting that behaviour, what I would do in that case is set the image inside computed properties, something like:

```
computed: {
  imageSrc() {
    return require('...');
  }
}
```

Like that you can ensure that the image will be set once webpack loads the image and your application behaviour doesn't get affected.

The rest is make some tweaks for the UI/UX, I would advice you to use something like Medium to show a placeholder until the image gets loaded, but that's up to you and your design :)
Cheers.

Comment: Hi bretanac, thanks for your help - just tried that but it didn't solve the problem.